# Find the minimums number m such that each subset of M also have two number a,b satisfied that a divisible to b.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $M=\left \{ 1,2,\ldots,2013 \right \}$. Find the minimum number $m$ such that all the subset of sizes $m$ also have two number $a$, $b$ satisfied that a divisible by $b$.
I can't do anything for this problem.

Comment: Maybe you mean subset, not sup-set?

Comment: What is the role of '$m$' ?

Comment: I think the question is, find the least $m$ such that if all subsets of size $m$ have this property. At least, that's a fairly standard combinatorics problem. @Avatar

Comment: i think you are right @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks you so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $m > 1007$ as the set $\{1007,1008,\ldots ,2013\}$ has no number dividing another. In general, if the original set is $\{1,2,\ldots ,2n-1\}$, then $m >n$. We now show that $m=n+1$.

Consider any $n+1$ numbers in the set. Write them in the form $2^rk$, where $k$ is odd. As there are only $n$ odd numbers in the set and $k$ must be present in the set, we must have a pair of numbers (among the $n+1$ picked) with same $k$. Then depending on which of these numbers had bigger $r$ value, one of them divides the other.

Note that $m=n$ even for the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,2n\}$ by similar arguments.